# Подмена URL с помощью htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно изменить URL вида
`http://site.ru/apartamenty` на
`http://site.ru/apart`.

Мой вариант:
`RewriteRule ^apart apartamenty [L]`
не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, нет под рукой Apache.

Попробуйте так:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^apartamenty$ apart [R=301,L] #, либо без перманентного редиректа [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @romeo, можно обойтись без `RewriteBase`.  
Перед apart лучше поставить слэш. Вот так:  

    RewriteRule ^apartamenty$ /apart [R=301,L]  

А протестировать `.htaccess` онлайн можно тут:  `http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/`

Comment: @VenZell Благодарю!